# Calculating actual angle between two vectors in Unity3D

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

Is there a way I can calculate the actual angle between two 3D Vectors in Unity? Vector3.Angle gives the shortest angle between the two vectors. I want to know the actual angle calculated in clockwise fashion.

Comment: What do you mean by the shortest angle? There's only one angle between two vectors. The angle is usually calculated by (conceptually) moving from the first vector in an arc toward the second vector.

Comment: I do not want the angle calculated by moving the first vector in clockwise or anticlockwise direction towards a Vector. In the implementation of Vector3.Angle, I get 90 degrees if Vector 2 is 90 degrees clockwise from Vector 1 or even if it is 270 degrees. I want it to return 270 degrees.

Comment: Answer that I just posted (and deleted) two seconds ago is obviously wrong, but I think that you'll definetly end up using dot product of these two vectors.

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you mean by "clockwise"? From what point to you want to look at these vectors and determine if they are clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: And what if from the point of view of the said point in space these vectors happen to project into one line? For example, if you want to determine "clockwiseness" of the vectors by looking from a point of (0,+9001,0), what about that lie in X-Y plane?

Comment: Yes I understand that can happen with 3D vectors. I used it for simplicity in understanding but I guess it was interpreted in the wrong way. Consider the Vectors to be on the XY Plane then with Z = 0. If Vector1 is (0, 1, 0) and Vector 2 is (-1, 0, 0), I want the result to be 270 degrees and not 90. The current implementation of Vector3.Angle does not give you an angle > 180 degrees because it does 360 - result if the Angle is > 180 degrees. I wanted to know if there is a way I can get that extra information if the angle is actually in fact 270 degrees. Hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should be what you need.  `a` and `b` are the vectors for which you want to calculate an angle, `n` would be the normal of your plane to determine what you would call "clockwise/counterclockwise"

```
float SignedAngleBetween(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 n){
    // angle in [0,180]
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(a,b);
    float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(n,Vector3.Cross(a,b)));

    // angle in [-179,180]
    float signed_angle = angle * sign;

    // angle in [0,360] (not used but included here for completeness)
    //float angle360 =  (signed_angle + 180) % 360;

    return signed_angle;
}
```

For simplicity I reuse `Vector3.Angle` and then calculate the sign from the magnitude of the angle between plane normal `n` and the cross product (perpendicular vector) of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Can you provide a usage example of the method please?

Comment: Jedrak's answer is great but if you want to get angles in the range of [0, 360) you must modify angle360 formula (write 360 instead of 180): float angle360 = (signed_angle + **360**) % 360;

Comment: Could you explain the Math behind this ? specially `float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(n,Vector3.Cross(a,b)));`

Comment: @UgoHed 2 vectors `a` and `b` define a plane but there is an implied 3rd vector, the cross product of the first 2, that defines the plane's normal.   Any angle between  `a` and `b` rotates around that 3rd axis.  So the problem is which way do we rotate?  The angle between 2 vectors is always a positive angle.  `Vector3.Angle(a,b) == Vector3.Angle(b,a)`. To find the direction of rotation we use the line you identified which essentially just compares the user's defined axis of rotation `n` against the implicit axis.  If a match, sign is positive, if not, sign is negative.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you just use addition and subtraction. Look at this:

```
/Degrees
  float signedAngleBetween (Vector3 a, Vector3 b, bool clockwise) {
  float angle = Vector3.angle(a, b);

  //clockwise
  if( Mathf.Sign(angle) == -1 && clockwise )
    angle = 360 + angle;

  //counter clockwise
  else if( Mathf.Sign(angle) == 1 && !clockwise)
    angle = - angle;
  return angle;
}
```

Here's what i mean:
if we are clockwise and the angle is negative, e.g. -170
to make it 180, you use this equation. "180-|angle|+180"
you already know that the angle is negative, so, use "180-(-angle)+180" and add the 180's "360 + angle".
Then if it's clockwise, **CONTINUE** but if it's counter clockwise, make the angle negative, this is because the other part of  the 360 angle (which is the compliment of 360 + angle) is "360 - (360 + angle)" or
"360 - 360 - angle" OR "(360 - 360) - angle" and, again, **OR** "- angle". So there we go... your finished angle.

Answer (score -8):

Try to use `Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);`

Since you want the shortest angle between them, then if the value returned is more than 180 degrees, just subtract 360 degrees with this value.

Check out http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/317648/angle-between-two-vectors.html

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, I am not looking for the shortest angle, but the angle considering the vectors' order.

Comment: Ok here's an idea: Check which quadrant the vector is in. For example, if the x component is positive and y component is negative, then that's in the 4th quadrant. Do it with your 2 vectors, and you will have an idea of their orientation relative to each other. Now, if both vectors happen to be within the same quadrant, just compute the angle between each of your vector to another vector, say the vector that lies between quadrant 1 and 4. From these angles, you should be able to determine their relative orientations.

Comment: I tried the same. This works partially but the same issue arises within the quadrant if I try comparing the Angle between the Vectors. A slight change to the last step though gives us a solution but it is still not convenient. Instead of checking the angle between a Vector and an arbitrary vector in that quadrant, you can compare the x components of the two Vectors within two quadrants. You still need to make sure both vectors are in the same quadrant halves else it won't work correctly.

Comment: If you look at the documentation, `Vector3.Angle` says: *"The angle returned is always the acute angle... never greater than 180 degrees"*. So this answer is not only answering a question the OP didn't ask, it contains misleading or wrong information too.